# Should Vertical Cities Need Industrial Plants?

Tags: construction

People around the world have been proposing building a "vertical city" as a means to deal with the growing issue of overpopulation.

But let's say that the New York or Chicago or San Francisco or any other cities built--or rebuilt--after the Great Chicago Fire were vertical cities.  If someplace like Manhattan became a vertical city between the 1880s and 1930s, would it still need industrial plants to process fossil fuels?  Or would a vertical city make fossil fuel refineries irrelevant?

Comment: How could building vertically render irrelevant the prevailing method of generating energy? Building vertically doesn't mean they don't still need power, heat, etc...

Comment: Is there a fossil fuel refinery in Manhattan somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

OF course they would need fossil fuels. Hydrocarbons provide the high energy density energy needed for an industrial society to run. In fact, they would need to use hydrocarbon fuels up to the time they convert over to nuclear energy (which is even more energy dense).

Hydrocarbons and coal would allow the cities to be built anywhere, and not be tethered to hydropower or watercourses. Hydrocarbons would power things like emergency generators, railroads to bring food to the city and bring waste materials out of the city, airship hangers on the roofs for flight (this was a popular trope up until the 1930's) and probably internal tramlines inside the building for heavy service transport.

There will also be industry for the people, including chemical production, plastics and fertilizers, all of which require petrochemicals as the base materials.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you propose a change to the historic power supply in addition to the alteration of architecture, power requirements will remain. (as mentioned)

If these cities are placed near hydraulic sources, much of the power required could come from that, but as the city grows larger, the more it will need. Harnessing and distributing that power is a major issue. Both aspects are exacerbated by the fact that lifting goods up costs energy.

Of *course* they would still need their fossil fuels and power plants.

(Unless, of course, you want to define a world with different thermodynamics, history, or both. That could be a very different scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

Industrial plants can do many things; heating water, cooling air, electricity, and dozens of other things.  All of these things need to be included in "vertical cities".

I'm not sure why you singled out oil refineries.  However, oil refineries produce many different products other than fuel oil, diesel, and gasoline.  They produce tar, plastics, rubber, fertilizers, etc.  Additionally, their output is used as feedstock for pesticides and many other industries and industrial processes.

If your "vertical city" included all the manufacturing that its residents needed (directly and indirectly), then it would require oil refineries too.